# Switch trunkports

Tags: cisco, switching, vlan

When I connect 2 switches I configure the involved ports as trunkports. On both ports I can also set which VLANs are permitted to use the trunkport. What happens if I set trunkport1 to let VLAN1, VLAN2 and VLAN3 through and thrunkport2 to let only VLAN1 and VLAN2 through, but not VLAN3. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged it as Cisco, so I will assume it is a Cisco Switch. If allowed vlans are different on each side of trunk, the ones that match will pass traffic, the ones that do not match, will be dropped. vlan1 and vlan2 will work, but vlan3 will be dropped by switch which doesn't have that vlan in allowed list.